# How to make a woocommerce product attribute value update with the value selected in a custom box on frontend of product's quick edit menu?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a code below that creates a custom box inside the woocommerce quick edit menu of a product which contains an html dropdown with all the values from the 'Brand' attribute.

- Photo of the Brand attribute:

[image]

- Photo of the Custom dropdown html inside the quick edit menu (Its highlighted in a red box):

[image]

**The Problem:**

If I have already set atleast one Brand attribute value in the backend of a product then the code works as intended and adds the value I selected in the dropdown from the quick menu, else if I have not yet set a value for the brand attribute in the product I am quick editting then after updating the quick edit menu the value does not appear in the backend of the product.

---

**The Code:**

This is the code I have in the functions.php of the theme:

```
function my_quick_edit_save_function($post_id) {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['post_ID']) == $post_id) {
        // Retrieve the selected brand value from the quick edit form
        $selected_brand = isset($_REQUEST['my_brand']) ? sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['my_brand']) : '';

        $product_id = $post_id; // Replace with the actual product ID
        $attribute_slug = 'pa_brand'; // Replace with the desired attribute slug

        // Assign the color attribute value to the product
        wp_set_object_terms($product_id, $value, $attribute_slug, true);
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'my_quick_edit_save_function');

function my_custom_quick_edit_fields() {

    $taxonomy = 'pa_brand'; // Replace with the actual taxonomy name of the attribute

    $terms = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ));

    if (!empty($terms)) {
        echo '<select name="my_brand">';
        echo '<option value="my_brand">' . __('Select Brand', 'woocommerce') . '</option>';

        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            echo '<option value="' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';
        }

        echo '</select>';
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_product_quick_edit_end', 'my_custom_quick_edit_fields', 10);
```

---

**Questions:**

- How can I modify this code to make it add the value I selected in the custom dropdown in quick edit menu even when I have not yet set any values for the brand attribute in the backend of a product?

*Thanks in advance for your time and effort!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing the my_quick_edit_save function by replacing the code inside the $_REQUEST if with this:

```
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $selected_brand, $attribute_slug, true );

        $att_var = Array($attribute_slug =>Array(
               'name'=>$attribute_slug,
               'value'=>$selected_brand,
               'is_visible' => '1',
               'is_taxonomy' => '1'
             ));

        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_attributes', $att_var );
```

Make sure that the attribute slug in the ATTRIBUTES section of woocommerce is 'brand' else the 'pa_brand' taxonomy slug won't work!